# wxWidgets running on other machine

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I created application which uses wxWidgets library using visual studio 2008. Now I would like to create version which may be run on other machine.

Because right now when I want to run It on another machine there is an error:
the application failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect.

What can I do to make It work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Event Viewer should have a record showing what DLL was being searched for, what version of that DLL if found in the SxS cache, and what version it was looking for but couldn't find. You'll then want to (for example) include the correct version of that DLL to be installed with your program. Alternatively, just link to virtually everything statically -- it'll make your executable a lot bigger, but eliminate a *lot* of problems like this relatively painlessly.